# Deserializing JSON with dynamic keys into dictionary

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have problems deserializing this JSON data structure comming from an API.
We have no possibilities to change the JSON data, so I need to serialize it as it is.

```
{"success":"1","return":{"balances_available":{"ALF":"0.00000000","AMC":"0.00000000","ADT":"0.00000000","ANC":"0.00000000"}}}
```

Currently I try this

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
balances = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as Response;

[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember(Name = "success")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "return")]
    public Balance Return { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Balance
{
    [DataMember(Name = "balances_available")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> BalancesAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

But my dictionary get 0 items, so it does not look like it is beeing serialized.
Are there no other way of fixing this than manually creating a class where I define all balance items (ALF, AMC, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` like this:

```
 var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true
                    };
 var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response), settings);
```

And this will be work. Good luck!